Can we remove all the constructor-based injections?
Recently, Angular put in place a migration to replace constructor-based injection with inject function.
In most of the cases, it is straightforward and it clearly has benefits:
// before
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SomeSearchService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(SEARCH_DUE_TIME)
    private readonly dueTime: number,
    private readonly repositoryService: SomeRepositoryService
  ) {}

// after: more concise, better typing
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SomeSearchService {
  private readonly dueTime = inject(SEARCH_DUE_TIME);
  private readonly repositoryService= inject(SomeRepositoryService);

However, can inject function cover all the constructor-based injection usages?
In particular with useFactory + deps?
To illustrate, I have this Stackblitz:
// print.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class PrintService implements IPrintService {
  constructor( // QUESTION: can I replace it with `inject` calls? 
    @Inject(DATA_SERVICE)
    private readonly dataService: IDataService,
    private readonly logger: LoggingService,
    ...
  ) {}

// tokens.ts
export const DATA_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<IDataService>('DATA_SERVICE');
export const FOO_PRINT_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<IPrintService>('FOO_PRINT_SERVICE');
export const BAR_PRINT_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<IPrintService>('BAR_PRINT_SERVICE');

// app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    {
      provide: FOO_PRINT_SERVICE,
      useFactory: (dataService: IDataService, logger: LoggingService) => new PrintService(dataService, logger),
      deps: [FOO_DATA_SERVICE, LoggingService],
    },
    {
      provide: BAR_PRINT_SERVICE ,
      useFactory: (dataService: IDataService, logger: LoggingService) => new PrintService(dataService, logger),
      deps: [BAR_DATA_SERVICE, LoggingService],
    },
    ...,
  ],
};

Is there a way to use inject & useFactory + deps together
so that I can replace the constructor declaration in my PrintService with inject calls?

As mentioned by 
Matthieu Riegler:
if you only rely on inject() you can remove the experimentalDecorators option from your TS config.

Yes, we can use them interchangeably.
Some scenarios will have injection decorators like skipSelf, Optional, Self, Host which can be provided as a second argument to an object containing these properties.
fooPrintService = inject(FOO_PRINT_SERVICE, {
  host: false,
  optional: false,
  self: false,
  skipSelf: false,
});

From your question perspective, all you need to do is pass the injection token to the inject method and it can detect it in DI tree.
import { Component, InjectionToken, Injectable, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class PrintService {
  constructor(public arg: string) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    {{fooPrintService.arg}} | {{barPrintService.arg}}
  `,
})
export class App {
    fooPrintService = inject(FOO_PRINT_SERVICE, {
      host: false,
      optional: false,
      self: false,
      skipSelf: false,
    });
  barPrintService = inject(BAR_PRINT_SERVICE);
  name = 'Angular';
}
export const DATA_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<any>('DATA_SERVICE');
export const FOO_PRINT_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<any>('FOO_PRINT_SERVICE');
export const BAR_PRINT_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<any>('BAR_PRINT_SERVICE');

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    {
      provide: FOO_PRINT_SERVICE,
      useFactory: () => new PrintService('foo'),
    },
    {
      provide: BAR_PRINT_SERVICE,
      useFactory: () => new PrintService('bar'),
    },
  ],
});

Stackblitz Demo

One could add that if you only rely on inject() you can remove the experimentalDecorators option from your TS config

@MatthieuRiegler updated thanks!

As I said, most of the cases are easily covered by inject and I know well those options ("host", "optional", etc.). This is not the point of my question. In my example, PrintService uses an @Inject() in its constructor and I use useFactory + deps to create my tokens. To rephrase my question (which I'll edit): if I use inject in PrintService to replace the constructor, then how can I create my tokens with the useFactory? Can we define a kind of injection scope to achieve this?

@fservantdev please use my stackblitz and modify it so that I can see what you are trying to achieve, we declare the token in either the standalone component providers array or bootstrap application environment providers array, we never use useFactory inside the constructor we simply access the configured provider.

About the experimentalDecorators (which is a bit off-topic), I guess that only relying on inject() is not the only condition, right? AFAIU, you also need to use input(), output(), viewChild(), host, ..., or do I miss something? Also, will the @Component decorator work without the experimentalDecorators ts option?

I know how to define providers and using useFactory "inside the constructor" is a weird idea. OK I will update the question with a stackblitz ;)

@fservantdev It could be due to the use of ES2022 that experimentalDecorators is not needed, but I am not sure about this. -> stackblitz without experimentalDecorators
